# How to package a single Python script with nix?

Tags: nix

I have a single Python script called `myscript.py` and would like to package it up as a `nix` derivation with `mkDerivation`.

The only requirement is that my Python script has a run-time dependency, say, for the `consul` Python library (which itself depends on the `requests` and `six` Python libraries).

For example for `myscript.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import consul
print('hi')
```

How to do that?

I can't figure out how to pass `mkDerivation` a single script (its `src` seems to always want a directory, or `fetchgit` or similar), and also can't figure out how to make the dependency libraries available at runtime.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you have a single Python file as your script, you don't need `src` in your `mkDerivation` and you also don't need to unpack any source code.

The default `mkDerivation` will try to unpack your source code; to prevent that, simply set `dontUnpack = true`.

```
myscript-package = pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "myscript";
  propagatedBuildInputs = [
    (pkgs.python3.withPackages (pythonPackages: with pythonPackages; [
      consul
      six
      requests2
    ]))
  ];
  dontUnpack = true;
  installPhase = "install -Dm755 ${./myscript.py} $out/bin/myscript";
};
```

If your script is executable (which we ensure with `install -m` above) Nix will automatically replace your `#!/usr/bin/env python3` line with one which invokes the right specific python interpreter (the one for `python36` in the example above), and which does so in an environment that has the Python packages you've specifified in `propagatedBuildInputs` available.

If you use NixOS, you can then also put your package into `environment.systemPackages`, and `myscript` will be available in shells on that NixOS.

Answer (score 10):

This helper function is really nice:

```
pkgs.writers.writePython3Bin "github-owner-repos" { libraries = [ pkgs.python3Packages.PyGithub ]; } ''
 import os
 import sys
 from github import Github

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     gh = Github(os.environ['GITHUB_TOKEN'])

     for repo in gh.get_user(login=sys.argv[1]).get_repos():
         print(repo.ssh_url)
''
```

https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/build-support/writers/default.nix#L319

Comment: This is wonderful! Should be more widely documented IMHO